Uneven filament printing with bubbles or drops
I got the following printing problems


I can suggest that it is happening stronger in one half

What can be the reason?
Printer is Creality 3D Ender, filament is marked as PLA.

This could be a sign of moisture in the filament or a worn out nozzle.
As it is heated, the moisture in the filament expands and produces bubbles/defects as it leaves the nozzle. If you hear popping while extruding at a slower flow rate you likely have wet filament. Particularly if this does not happen with other filaments you should first attempt to dry it.
Since you mentioned noticing a bias as to where the defect occurs there is also a possibility this is a worn out nozzle. A worn out nozzle can have an oblong oriface, which leads to asymmetrical and flawed extrusion. I think this is less likely to be your problem (depending on the hours on the nozzle) but it is worth keeping in mind.
If you could share your sliced file it would be helpful for ruling out slicing issues too.
